# HTML5 video won't display

Tags: html, video

I am trying to display a video on a webpage.
I tested it locally and it works fine. However, when I put it in my webpage's repository (on a different computer) and access it through the internet, the video does not appear.

I included an mp4 and an ogg as source files, and tested it on both Firefox and Chrome, but neither work. I am sure the video path is correct.

Any thoughts?

```html
<video width="205", controls>
 <source src="movies/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 <source src="movies/video1.ogv" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
Videos did not have read access.